# Substract series from a fixed value in Graphite

Tags: graphite

I'm trying to graph CPU usage in Graphite with something like `100 - ganglia.box.cpu.cpu_idle`, but every single function requires a time series as parameter.  It seems `Offset` function almost does the trick, but only allows to offset a time series by a fixed value, not the other way around.

Is there a way to do this in Graphite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to do this. Just as an immediate idea:
offset(scale(ganglia.box.cpu.cpu_idle,-1),100)